# Phonegap white blink when data-ajax="false"

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-build

In built Phonegap html/js app there are white blinks when navigating betwen pages on Android and ios.Using Angular and jquery, but all links have data-ajax="false" so no ajax or transitions are used.(removed jquery but the problem didn't solve)

I tried:

```
1.) .ui-page {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden !important;
}

2.) <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

3.) changing default background

```
body{
    background-image:url(images/backgrounds/eni0.png) !important;
    background-size:cover !important;

}
```

But nothing above worked.

Do you have any more ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A single page application design pattern is a best practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't use the ajax navigation then you are changing from one html page to another, and with this page navigation the blink will appear, there is nothing you can't do to avoid this, the blink is due to the navigation.

The options here are using the ajax navigation, so you are always on the first page and get and display the second page content without navigating to a different html, or using fade out - fade in animations before changing from one html to another, you won't really remove the blink, but "hide" it.